# i want get audio files in sd card

Tags: android, audio, ringtone

In my app I want to set the `ringtone` when I get an incoming call... How to open the `SDCARD` and get *audio files* and list it.. How to get the `URI` for the selected `audio file`..

Comment: Please clear it out do you want `files in sdcard` or `from sdcard`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MediaScanner finds music for you, populating the MediaStore database. Here's some code to look up a music entry:

```
final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] cursor_cols = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    };
    final String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";
    final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, cursor_cols, where, null, null);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    final String artist = cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
    final String album = cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
    final String track = cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
    doSomethingHere(artist, album, track);
```

The "data" field contains a handle you can use with MediaPlayer. while doing this media files scanning and indexing for the first time, scan it using a AsyncTask, but later when a intent is received do it using a service.