# How to provide an option, for the user, to select music with in android application?

Tags: android, android-music-player

I am new to Android, I need a path to fulfill my requirements. In my application I need to provide an option for the user to select their playlist from the application. Is this possible?, please confirm.

I tried this with the following sample code, in the following code I tried to get the files from sd card and display them in list view. When I try to run the application I got force close. Could you please look into this and suggest me if I am doing anything wrong.

My test class.

```
public class TestMediaActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
private int currentPosition = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    updateSongList();
}
public void updateSongList() 
{
    System.out.println("In the updateSongList");
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n In the condition length>0");
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                    songs.add(file.getName());
            }

            setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.test_item, songs));
    }

}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("In the setListAdapter");
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    currentPosition = position;
    playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
}
private void playSong(String songPath) {
    try {

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            // Setup listener so next song starts automatically
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                            nextSong();
                    }

            });

    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void nextSong() {
    if (++currentPosition >= songs.size()) {
        // Last song, just reset currentPosition
        currentPosition = 0;
} else {
        // Play next song
        playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
}
}


}
```

And supporting class is ,

```
public class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter 
{

@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("In the Mp3Filter");
    return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
   }

}
```

And the error in the log cat is....

```
 08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       start activity     ComponentInfo{com.vsoft.TestMedia/com.vsoft.TestMedia.TestMediaActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at  com.vsoft.TestMedia.TestMediaActivity.updateSongList(TestMediaActivity.java:36)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at com.vsoft.TestMedia.TestMediaActivity.onCreate(TestMediaActivity.java:29)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
08-15 14:49:35.800: E/AndroidRuntime(31871):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: you can list all the audio files in the sdcard and make the user to select any of the audio file so that he can play it

Comment: @ Sharath, Thanks for your quick response. Can you please share any sample code to do that.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590628/i-want-get-audio-files-in-sd-card 
or 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible. You'll probably want to use a `ListView` to display the songs using checkable list items. Then hook the `ListView` up to a `SimpleAdapter` that you've written. The `Adapter` will need to fetch the song titles from the SD card (or wherever you're keeping them), and then provide the `ListView` with the appropriate list items.

**EDIT**

```
File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
```

is the problem. `home` is `null`. The reason it's `null` is because the file isn't found. You shouldn't use `/sdcard/` to access the SD card because the SD card directory is device-dependent. What you want is:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: @ Mike, Thanks for your quick solution, I did a sample application and tried, but got error. Could you please check this? (I edited my question with code please take a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: I just posted the error log, could you please check and suggest me If I doing anything wrong

Comment: Your problem is a null pointer except at TestMediaActivity.java line 36. Could you please indicate where that is.

Comment: @ Mike, if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0)  this is the code at line number 36.

Comment: Got it, I will try with that and let you know Mike. Thanks for all your support

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15374/discussion-between-chandrasekhar-and-mike-t)

Comment: Sorry for the delay:). Mike Is it possible to load Music picker, which will provide option to select tracks, playlists and albums?

Comment: no prob. I'm not sure how that would work. You'd have to open the MP3s somehow and inspect the file

Comment: No problem Mike, I will investigate on that. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried that with Audio, but can't you just create an intent with filter "audio/*" and call activity for result on it?