# Media files information not updating on ContentResolver.query

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I am writing an android app that allows me to update media files.
I have an AsyncTask that (among other things) scans the device for media files.

The code below is the method used to get all the media files and create a list of FileInfo (my class, holding basic meta data of files).

The problem is that the data received from the `Cr().query` is always the same and not bringing the latest updates.

I have looked at [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338375/android-contentresolver-query-always-returns-same-data) but you can see that my code does the solution recommended there, yet I still get the old data rather than the refreshed.

Took me a while to figure out this is the problem, but I now see it clearly in the output of the log statement `Log.d("scanLocalFiles", "" + fileInfos.size() + "|" + data + ":" + size );`
that a file that I know that has been changed, still appears with its original size.
(I know it has been changed because I see the updated one on ES-FileExplorer...)

Any suggestion of what might be going on?

Thanks.

Code below:

```
private List<FileInfo> scanLocalFiles(Uri... uris)
{
    List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE
    };
    for (int u=0; u < uris.length; u++)
    {
        Uri uri = uris[u];

        //Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cur = Cr().query(uri,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                "",         // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                ""          // Ordering
                );

        if(cur!=null && cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            try
            {
                int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                int dataColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
                int sizeColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(projection[2]);
                int mimeColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(projection[3]);
                do
                {
                    Uri id = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, cur.getString(idColumn));
                    String data = cur.getString(dataColumn);
                    long size = cur.getLong(sizeColumn);
                    String mime = cur.getString(mimeColumn);
                    Log.d("scanLocalFiles", "" + fileInfos.size() + "|" + data + ":" + size );
                    fileInfos.add(new FileInfo(id, data, size, mime));

                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {

                cur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return fileInfos;
}
```